# Windows fails to start but can still see data through command prompt

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bsod

I have a desktop computer running Windows 10. The fan was making a noise so I cleaned it out. I think I was too aggressive and sprayed the compressed air right on the SATA connection to the SSD. Anyway, next time I turned on the computer it went into startup repair mode and gave the error

> A required device isn't connected or cannot be accessed
>   Error code: 0xc000000e

I rebooted a few times and got a different error message:

> Your PC did not start correctly
>   where it gives me the option to choose advanced options and open a terminal

I tried following the instructions [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/a-required-device-isnt-connected-or-cannot-be-accessed) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/total-identified-windows-installations-0/52359f87-de4a-41dc-b0c3-cc275e1d9fbf) but they did not work. When I run `bootrec /rebuildbcd` it gives "Windows Installations 0" and the directory C:\boot is missing. I ran checkdsk and believe it repaired some things. I disconnected secondary hard drive, all non essential peripherals

Through the command prompt I can access my files so I know at least that's still there. What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a hardware problem, where you have caused a bad connection.

I would suggest to open up the computer and verify all connections, re-seating
them if necessary.

If this doesn't help, bring the computer to repair-man that will have the
tools to locate the damage.

Comment: It turned out the SATA cable connecting the SSD to mobo was damaged. Funny enough, the computer repair man misdiagnosed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

### Option 1

You can attempt a windows repair using your computer's recovery disk or windows installation CD.

On the Choose an option screen, select **Troubleshoot**. From there, you can:

- Restore from a system restore point by selecting **Advanced options** > **System Restore**. This will remove **recently installed** apps, drivers, and updates that might be causing your PC problems. Restoring from a restore point won’t affect your personal files.
- Select **Reset this PC** to reinstall Windows 10. This will remove **all** apps and drivers you installed and changes you made to settings, but lets you choose to keep or remove your personal files.

### Option 2

You can carry out a complete reinstall of windows using the recovery disk or windows installation disk.

### If you choose Option 2

remember to back up any data you wish to keep on your windows partition.

### If you don't have either your recovery disk or windows installation CD

you can legally download a **free copy** of Windows 10 installation CD using a working computer.  Just go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

When installation asks for a product key  just say you don't have one.  Because you already had Windows 10 installed and activated, it will reactivate automatically.

Comment: I try to repair from bootable USB. But get "Access is denied" when I run `bootrec /FixBoot`

Comment: Boot into the USB and when it comes up, select 'repair windows'

Comment: A technician repaired it by recovering from a System Restore point. I didn't know System Restore could be used if Windows couldn't start in the first place?

Comment: @northerner - that is option 1 using the windows 10 installation CD or USB. Select 'Repair your computer' instead of installing windows. 
I have edited my answer to make it clearer